# Is there a way in Vue to convert military time into standard time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, bootstrap-vue

I am fetching military time from JSON API using the code below.

```
mounted: function(){
    var currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    axios.get("https://mysiteurl.com/api/ordersseller=5e1f43c0c69e7&items.arrival="+currentDate)
     .then(response => (this.post = response.data.data));
},

data(){
    return{
      post: []
   }
}


// the time value that I receive through that API is 1500, 1600 and 1700
```

This is the template view which displays the time above.

```
<div v-for="item in post.items" v-bind:key="item.arrival">
    {{item.arrivalTime}}
</div>
```

How can I convert **military time** values like 1500, 1600 and 1700 **into standard time**, so that they get print as 03:00 PM, 04:00 PM and 05:00 PM in **Vue.js**?

Comment: use moment -> [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), in a [filter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform item values in a retrieved list further

```js
mounted: function(){
    var currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    axios.get("https://mysiteurl.com/api/ordersseller=5e1f43c0c69e7&items.arrival="+currentDate)
     .then(response => {
      this.post = response.data.data.map(pr => ({
      ...pr,
      arrivalTime: moment(pr.arrivalTime, "HHmm").format("hh:mm A")
      })
}
);
},

data(){
    return{
      post: []
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```js
let time = militaryTime/100-12 + ":00";
```

?

Comment: Not only they're not padded `1500` will result into `3:00` instead of `03:00`, nor do they have `AM/PM`, but also `300` (3 am) will end up as `-9:00`. Amazing.

Comment: It's just a concept. Of course if would need some polishing... :)